# Not able to parse windows path with space in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to execute a windows command from python.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\VTune Amplifier 2018\bin64\amplxe-cl" -collect general-exploration-0 -app-working-dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" --duration 180 -- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`

python is not able to parse this part

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
```

I tried breaking up the query to narrow down the issue and tried using raw strings as well and forward slashes.
Heres my code

```
import os
a =r'"C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/VTune Amplifier 2018/bin64/amplxe-cl.exe"'
b=r' -collect general-exploration-0 -app-working-dir '
c= r"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application"
d=r' --duration 180 -- '
e=r'"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"'

z = a + b + c  + d + e 
os.system(z)
```

I am getting Error as `'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Which is due to 'c' string in code.

Comment: try with a =r"C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/VTune Amplifier 2018/bin64/amplxe-cl.exe".....note i removed single inverted comma

Comment: Not working...same error

Answer (score 1):

Python passes the command to Command Prompt as if you ran it with `cmd.exe /C <command>`. 
Command Prompt decides whether to keep the first and last double quotation marks based on the criteria that can be seen by running `cmd.exe /?`.

Printing the value of `z`, one gets `"C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/VTune Amplifier 2018/bin64/amplxe-cl.exe" -collect general-exploration-0 -app-working-dir C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application --duration 180 -- "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"`. This string does not pass all of the tests required to keep its quotation marks, so the first step is to wrap the whole thing in another pair of quotation marks: `z = '"' + a + b + c + d + e + '"'`.

However, the argument to `app-working-dir` is also unquoted, so `c` needs to be changed to `c= r'"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application"'`. Now `print z` will return `""C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/VTune Amplifier 2018/bin64/amplxe-cl.exe" -collect general-exploration-0 -app-working-dir "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application" --duration 180 -- "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe""`, and `os.system(z)` will work, as long as the files and directories in the command exist.

An alternative approach is to use 8.3 short filenames and avoid quotation marks altogether, such that `z` is `C:/PROGRA~2/IntelSWTools/VTUNEA~1/bin64/amplxe-cl.exe -collect general-exploration-0 -app-working-dir C:/PROGRA~2/Google/Chrome/Application --duration 180 -- C:/PROGRA~2/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe`. The short names here (like `PROGRA~2`) are my guesses on what they might be; run the command `DIR /X` in the parent directory to see what the actual short name is on a specific system.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is because of the fact that `\` is acting as an escape character in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`.

Your Solution can be resolved by following the instructions on [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Let me know if you still have issues, cheers!

Comment: If you mean using forward slash in the code I am doing that.

Comment: I think I see where the issue is, you typed

`e=r'"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"'`
instead of

`e=r"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"`

Comment: If i try to execute only 'e', It works fine. I think 'c ' is creating error

Comment: try putting in `--app-working-dir` instead of `-app-working-dir` then try it and let me know

Comment: So from what I understand, the issue lies in python not understanding what `r"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application"` is. So when you pass it to the OS it thinks that it is part of a new command and not part of the argument. Which is why I suggested `--`. That's why it complains that `'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` Did you try running the command in cmd prompt to make sure that it runs there correctly?

Comment: If that doesn't work try putting an `=` for whichever argument it belongs to, like `--app-working-dir=C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application`

Comment: tried both.
is there any other better way to execute the command rather than os.system() ?

Comment: I created a .bat file with the command and calling that from python, for now.

Comment: good point! let me post that as an answer since not enough space here

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use the subprocess library, you could spawn a thread to do the job and continue working in parallel or wait on the thread. This is how you would do it (or something like this).

```
import subprocess

cmd = ["C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/VTune Amplifier 2018/bin64/amplxe-cl.exe", "-collect general-exploration-0 -app-working-dir", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application", "--duration 180 --", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"]

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

if p.wait() > 0:
    print "Error"
else:
    print "Success"
```

Or

```
try:
    p = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
except Exception as e:
    print "Error: ", e
```